# Zend Studio and MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp, zend-studio

Do you use Zend Studio on a Mac? Do you use it with MAMP or Zend Server CE? Can you share your experience? How hard/easy was it to configure for either server? Has it helped your development productivity much, say, over Eclipse+PDT (which is free)?

Basically, I'm trying to decide if it's worth buying Zend Studio. And, since I'm on a Mac, how hard it is to configure for use with MAMP.

Comment: Zend Server CE on a mac is a breeze and IMHO far better than mamp - but sorry I cannot answer your question as I haven't used studio. Eclipse+PDT plus good debugger like XDebug is highly recommended though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using MAMP + Zend Studio for 2 years. Then switched to Zend Studio + Zend Server CE. I see no gain in using zend server ce. Right now I've left Zend Studio to a better ide: PhpStorm. Give it a try. I's full featured and not as heavy as zend studio.

Comment: Can you provide a link to Phpcharm?

Comment: I confused with the name of an IDE from the same company PyCharm for python. The name of the IDE for PHP is PhpStorm. It's because they are basically the same, except with the language supported. I use both.